# Ignore words with '

Tags: python

I need to count all unique five letter words in a txt file and ignore any word with an
apostrophe. I'm new to python so I am quite confused trying to get just the five letter words and not sure how to ignore words that have an ' .
what I wrote so far seemed to work for filtering the unique words but not for just five letter words.

```
with open ("names.txt", 'r') as f:  #open the file
    words = f.read().lower().split()  #read the contents into a sting, made all the character in string lower case and split string into list of words
    print(words)     


unique_words = set(words) #get unique words
print(len(unique_words)) 

for w in unique_words:
    if len(w) == 5:
       print(unique_words)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Looks quite good. What's your question? Use `if "'" in word:` to check for the apostrophe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good. I think the only bit you did wrong was to `print(unique_words)` instead of `print(w)` when you found a word `w` of length 5.

To ignore the words containing `'` you can add this condition:

```
for w in unique_words:
    if len(w) == 5 and "'" not in w:
       print(w)
```

B.t.w. you don't need the `pass` statement if you are already at the end of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
with open("names.txt", 'r') as f:  #open the file
    words = f.read().lower().split()  #read the contents into a sting, made all the character in string lower case and split string into list of words
    print(words)     

unique_words = set() #Create empty set
for w in words:
    if len(w) == 5 and "'" not in w:
       unique_words.add(w) #add words to set

print(len(unique_words))
```